# minikube mount crashes: mount system call fails

Tags: macos, kubernetes, virtualbox, minikube

I am running minikube on my mac (running OSX 10.14.5)

minikube version: 1.1.0

minikube is using VirtualBox

I would like to have a single set of kubernetes yaml files that I use in different environments. Therefore, I'm trying to mount the same directory I would use in other environments into my minikube. (If there's a different way to go about this but ease development let me know.)

Anyway, the mount fails.

```
$ minikube mount /etc/vsc:/etc/vsc
  Mounting host path /etc/vsc into VM as /etc/vsc ...
  Mount options:
    ▪ Type:     9p
    ▪ UID:      docker
    ▪ GID:      docker
    ▪ Version:  9p2000.L
    ▪ MSize:    262144
    ▪ Mode:     755 (-rwxr-xr-x)
    ▪ Options:  map[]
  Userspace file server: ufs starting

  mount failed: mount: /etc/vsc: mount(2) system call failed: Connection timed out.
: Process exited with status 32
```

Comment: Can you check what the kubelet logs say about this? `minikube ssh` and once logged in try `journalctl -u kubelet.service -b`. Additionally, you can [debug Minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/debugging.md) using the `--v=n` flag when mounting your volume. Maybe that sheds light as well.

Comment: @YahI went in just now, and go figure it seems to work. Thanks for the advice. Regarding the "minikube ssh": I think this is only showing the current logs since minikube started running, right? My command above was actually crashing minikube, so I don't believe logs were showing from before the crash. Using --v=7 was helpful, however.